# Symfony2 - Is there anyway to implement something like jsf fragments?

Tags: symfony

I mean, some code that has his own logic related to a specific twig template and a related logic in a controller INSIDE another page.

Something like a bar with specific data for a user. Name, State, Phone number and some services and
this logic included I want to include it into pages where I decide to. Just reusing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just render a controller that returns that data from your views or make a service which fetches the data and expose it to twig.

### 1. Controller Example

#### Controller

```
class UserDataController extends Controller
{
    public function userDataAction()
    {
        $userData = // fetch user data....

        return $this->render('user_data_fragment_template.html.twig', ['user_data' => $userData]);
    }
}
```

#### Some template where you want to show that fragment

```
<div>{{ render(controller('YourBundle:UserDataController:userData')) }}</div>
```

### 2. Service Example

#### Data Provider Service

```
class UserDataProvider
{
    public function __construct(...)
    {
        ....
    }

    public function getUserData()
    {
        $userData = // fetch user data...

        return $userData;
    }
}
```

#### config.yml

```
// ...

twig:
    globals:
        user_data_provider: @your_user_data_provider_service_name
```

#### Some template where you want to show that fragment

```
<div>{% include 'user_data_fragment_template.html.twig' with { userData: user_data_provider.userData } only %}</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Igor. But what if the template need a value? I'm getting this error 

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Controller "MMclasificadossvBundle:Example:testAjaxItem{1}" for URI "/_fragment" is not callable.") in MMclasificadossvBundle:Example\Fragment:cityInfo.html.twig at line 11.

Comment: In order to past variables I used

{{ render(controller('MMclasificadossvBundle:Example:testAjaxItem', { 'id': 1})) }}

Comment: And that's exactly how it is supposed to be used :)